# How to handle session value interpretation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following schema.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REF_CONNECTION1;
CREATE TABLE  REF_CONNECTION1 (
  BPIN INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  RIN INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  SRC_RIN INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BPIN,RIN,SRC_RIN)
);

INSERT INTO REF_CONNECTION1 VALUE(14,1,2);
INSERT INTO REF_CONNECTION1 VALUE(14,1,3);
INSERT INTO REF_CONNECTION1 VALUE(14,1,4);
INSERT INTO REF_CONNECTION1 VALUE(14,1,5);
INSERT INTO REF_CONNECTION1 VALUE(14,1,6);
INSERT INTO REF_CONNECTION1 VALUE(14,1,7);

SET @S1 = '2,3,4';

SELECT * FROM REF_CONNECTION1 WHERE SRC_RIN IN (@S1);
```

Result Set is giving only 1 row, but it should have given 3 rows. I am understanding why it is happening because it is actually converting to following query

```
SELECT * FROM REF_CONNECTION1 WHERE SRC_RIN IN ('2,3,4');
```

But I want it to look like following query.

```
SELECT * FROM REF_CONNECTION1 WHERE SRC_RIN IN (2,3,4);
```

How can I do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use INSTR and CAST, but I wouldn't recommend it on a large data set

```
    SELECT * FROM REF_CONNECTION1 
   WHERE INSTR(','+@S1+',',','+CAST(src_rin as CHAR(1))+',') > 0
```

It gives you the flexibility, but performance will not be great

Apparently mySQL treats ','+@S1+',' as a single character (as shown by the following).  Use CONCAT as I show in the modified code below, and it works properly

```
SELECT @s1,","+@s1+",",CONCAT(",",@S1,",")
FROM REF_CONNECTION1
WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(',',@S1,','),','+CAST(src_rin AS CHAR(1))+',') >0
```

Comment: Just keep performance in mind, SQL cannot optimize queries very well when you have functions like that in the WHERE clause

Comment: Apart from the performance, it's plain wrong! Let `@S1` be '234, 345, 456' your query will not only return the rows where src_rin is 234, 345 or 456, it will also return 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 23, 34, 45 and so on...

Comment: @VardanGupta Please have a look at my comment above. This solution is wrong.

Comment: Based on your sample data, the original query was right, but as FancyPants points out, it can fail with larger numbers.   I've modified the query to address the issue raised by Fancy

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca0d9/1/1 Your query does not even produce the right result with the limited sample data. My advice, forget about this INSTR() function.

Comment: See my modified query above, I am not sure why mySQL produces an unexpected result with ","+@S1+","...

Comment: @fancyPants I havle already CAST my src_rin to CHAR(10), which is done purposefully(,covering the point what you are concerned about) and doing my job.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a prepared statement for this:

```
SET @S1 = '2,3,4';

set @sql = concat('SELECT * FROM REF_CONNECTION1 WHERE SRC_RIN IN (', @S1, ');');
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```